Iterate throught records in psql in a function
first, i have never wrote an function with loops in psql. I tried to create functions without loops and it works very well.
Now my problem is i have 2 functions one for the outer loop and one for the inner loop. I need all values as return values in a table. I get records from the outer loop and i need the id of every record to iterate throught the inner loop. And from the inner loop i need the data of the records.
The error message i get in DBeaver is:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "record".

Here is the function:
create or replace function get_sale_orders_with_different_partner_payment_terms()
returns table(id int, name varchar, operating_unit_id int, create_date date)
as
$$
    declare 
        outer_record record;
        inner_record record;
        begin
            for outer_record in select * from get_customer_number_of_customers_with_sale_orders(false)
            loop
                for inner_record in select * from get_sale_order_ids_of_different_partner_payment_terms_of_cust(outer_record.customer_number);
                loop
                    select id, name, operating_unit_id, create_date from inner_record;
                end loop;
            end loop;
        end;
$$
language sql;

I have no ideas and i do not find a similar example for it.
Have anyone a idea or a better solution for my intend?
